# Echoing images out in side php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello im trying to echo out a image in side pagenation but is just showing /

Im using

```
echo  '<img src=http://myurl.net/"'.$row['Pokemon_pic'].'" title="" alt="" />';
```

But its just echoing out /  On the page i have echoed out the row Pokemon_pic out and shows the url of the image fine. e.g img/pokemon/397.png then im trying to put my domain name in front of it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the quote to the start of `src` attribute:

```
echo  '<img src="http://myurl.net/'.$row['Pokemon_pic'].'" title="" alt="" />';
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat will mark it correct when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the " in front of http which results in broken html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   echo  '<img src="http://myurl.net/'.$row['Pokemon_pic'].'" title="" alt="" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in image url

```
echo  '<img src="http://myurl.net/'.$row['Pokemon_pic'].'" title="" alt="" />';
```